# Type inference of a function in GHCi differs with loaded from a file

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I wrote a function `add'` in `test.hs`:

```
add' = \x y -> x + y
```

Then I loaded `test.hs` in GHCi (version 7.8.3), and typed `:t add'` to watch what type `add'` is. The result looks like incorrect:

```
*Main> :t add'
add' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

But if I typed `:t (\x y -> x + y)` straightly in GHCi, the result is correct:

```
*Main> :t (\x y -> x + y)
(\x y -> x + y) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Then I tried to rewrite the `add'` in `test.hs` as followed and `:type` them in GHCi:

```
add1 = \x y -> x + y
add2 = \x -> \y -> x + y
add3 x y = x + y
```

The results are:

```
add1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
add2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
add3 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

But use `let` clause to define a function and then `:type` them or `:type` the lambdas straightly in GHCi **all** results in type of `Num a => a -> a -> a`

Why are they different? Is it a bug of GHC?

Comment: Note that `add1` and `add2` are completely equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have hit upon the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). Monomorphism restriction makes the type signature of your function specialized to a single type. You can turn off that using the extension `NoMonomorphismRestriction`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

add1 = \x y -> x + y
add2 = \x -> \y -> x + y
add3 x y = x + y
```

And then when you load the types in ghci they will be:

```
λ> :t add1
add1 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
λ> :t add2
add2 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
λ> :t add3
add3 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Comment: Note that this behaviour is documented [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html).